# Do I use: While, for, or do-while?

Tags: c++, for-loop, while-loop

I've been going through a really useful list of programs to create on the C++ forum:

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/12974/

I'm currently on the third program called while(user==gullible).The forum is saying I should learn how to use for, while, do-while loops for this particular program, which gets the user to input any number other than the attempt number (so if the attempt number is 1, the program will output "Enter any number other than 1:"). I can get the program to end if the user enters the attempt number but i want the program to end at ten attempts which is what I'm having problems with. My program so far is as follows:

```
int main()

{
    int numberOfAttempts = 0;
    int userGuess;
    cout << "Enter any number other than " << numberOfAttempts << ": ";
    cin >> userGuess;

    while (userGuess != numberOfAttempts)
    {
        numberOfAttempts += 1;
        cout << "Enter any number other than " << numberOfAttempts << ": ";
        cin >> userGuess;
    }

    if (userGuess == numberOfAttempts)
    {
        cout << "Hey! I told you to enter any number other than " << numberOfAttempts << "!";
        return 0;
    }

    if (numberOfAttempts == 10)
    {
        cout << "Wow! You're a hell of a lot more patient than me! You win.";
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I'm having the problem where the program completely ignores the last "if" statement. I'm not looking for someone to solve my problem, I just need a bit of guidance. What should I be using (if I should be) other than the "while" and "if" statements?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Of course it ignores it, if you put your `if` OUTSIDE of the loop...

Comment: So is it as simple as including my if statements inside the while statement? @Nidhoegger

Comment: The process of executing any loop involves performing the operations *inside the loop's body* repeatedly zero or more times until the loop's exit condition is satisfied at the point where it is tested (before each iteration for `for` and `while` loops; after each iteration for `do ... while`).  Statements outside the loop body are not (directly) involved.

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` statements are outside your loop:

```
while (userGuess != numberOfAttempts)
{
    numberOfAttempts += 1;
    cout << "Enter any number other than " << numberOfAttempts << ": ";
    cin >> userGuess;

    if (userGuess == numberOfAttempts)
    {
        cout << "Hey! I told you to enter any number other than " << numberOfAttempts << "!";
        return 0;
    }

    if (numberOfAttempts == 10)
    {
        cout << "Wow! You're a hell of a lot more patient than me! You win.";
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This is what you are looking for. As for your comment: You can put as many scopes in-between as youd like. If you want your `if` to be executed in every loop-round, of course you have to include it WITHIN the loop brackets.

Answer (score 1):

You have to place your following `if` condition inside `while` loop if you prefer to run maximum 10 times  and you enter value 10 as `userGuess`

```
if (numberOfAttempts == 10)
    {
        cout << "Wow! You're a hell of a lot more patient than me! You win.";
        return 0;
    }
```